# How do I delete the previous saved image and save the new one without duplicating? Django

Tags: django, image, profile, django-2.0, imagefield

I'm having trouble saving image. My Model is this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pic')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self, **kwargs):
    super().save()

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

This model has and OneToOne relation field with the default user model and an image field.

I am overriding the save() method to rezize the image.

But

When I'm saving image with this model, It's saved with and automatic unique name. See the image below,

[Screenshot of file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvKyb.png)

But I want to save image like this..

> If user uploads an image, it'll delete the previous image of the user
>   and it'll save the new image with an unique name.

*How do I do it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using signals

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_init, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from myapp.models import Profile


@receiver(post_init, sender= Profile)
def backup_image_path(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance._current_imagen_file = instance.image


@receiver(post_save, sender= Profile)
def delete_old_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, '_current_image_file'):
        if instance._current_image_file != instance.image.path:
            instance._current_image_file.delete(save=False)
```